# Transfer multidimensional lua array from lua_State to lua_State C++

Tags: c++, lua

I have 2 scripts, each are in a different lua_State.

I am trying to be able to get a variable from one state and use it in the other.

My code below works for single variables and unidirectional arrays. Could I get some guidance on also making it work for multidimensional arrays?

```
void getValues(lua_State* L1, lua_State* L2, int& returns)
{
    if (lua_isuserdata(L1, -1))
    {
        LuaElement* e = Luna<LuaElement>::to_object(L1, -1);
        if (e != NULL)
        {
            Luna<LuaElement>::push_object(L2, e);
        }
    }
    else if (lua_isstring(L1, -1))
    {
        lua_pushstring(L2, lua_tostring(L1, -1));
    }
    else if (lua_isnumber(L1, -1))
        lua_pushnumber(L2, lua_tonumber(L1, -1));
    else if (lua_isboolean(L1, -1))
        lua_pushboolean(L2, lua_toboolean(L1, -1));
    else if (lua_istable(L1, -1))
    {
        lua_pushnil(L1);
        lua_newtable(L2);
        while (lua_next(L1, -2))
        {
            getValues(L1, L2, returns);

            lua_rawseti(L2,-2,returns-1);
            lua_pop(L1, 1);
        }
        // lua_rawseti(L2,-2,returns); // this needs work
    }
    returns++;
}
```

Unfortunately I'm having a tough time getting the recursion right for this to work for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `lua_type`, rather than repeated `lua_is*` calls?

Comment: Yeah that might be more efficient too considering integers are placed in isstring since isstring is before isnumber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

For anyone this might be useful:

```
void getValues(lua_State* L1, lua_State* L2, int ind)
{
    if (lua_type(L1, -1) == LUA_TTABLE)
    {
        lua_newtable(L2);
        lua_pushnil(L1);
        ind = 0;
        while (lua_next(L1, -2))
        {
            // push the key
            if (lua_type(L1, -2) == LUA_TSTRING)
                lua_pushstring(L2, lua_tostring(L1, -2));
            else if (lua_type(L1, -2) == LUA_TNUMBER)
                lua_pushnumber(L2, lua_tonumber(L1, -2));
            else
                lua_pushnumber(L2, ind);

            getValues(L1, L2, ind++);
            lua_pop(L1, 1);

            lua_settable(L2, -3);
        }
    }
    else if (lua_type(L1, -1) == LUA_TSTRING)
    {
        lua_pushstring(L2, lua_tostring(L1, -1));
    }
    else if (lua_type(L1, -1) == LUA_TNUMBER)
    {
        lua_pushnumber(L2, lua_tonumber(L1, -1));
    }
    else if (lua_type(L1, -1) == LUA_TBOOLEAN)
    {
        lua_pushboolean(L2, lua_toboolean(L1, -1));
    }
    else if (lua_type(L1, -1) == LUA_TUSERDATA)
    {
        // replace with your own user data. This is mine
        LuaElement* e = Luna<LuaElement>::to_object(L1, -1);
        if (e != NULL)
        {
            Luna<LuaElement>::push_object(L2, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Warning: L1 and L2 must be different states.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [lua_tinker::table:](https://github.com/zupet/LuaTinker)

Comment: There is a another method: *void getValues(lua_State* L1, lua_State* L2, const char* cszFormat, ...)* ,for example: cszFormat = "sd>ds", there are two input(string,number) and two output(number,string)